Any open subset $A$ of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a UNIQUE countable union of disjoint intervals open in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.
Here, I treat an open interval in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ as a topologically open interval in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$
I affirm: Any open subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is a UNIQUE countable union of disjoint intervals open in $\mathbb{R}$.
First, there are several questions in this site stating this result, but without the unicity, so my question is not repeated. In addition, I will give a very good different aproach to the proof.
To show this, consider the following lemma:
(Lemma 1) Let $A$ be as in the hypothesis. Let $(a_j)_{j\in J}$ and $(b_j)_{j\in J}$ be families of extended real numbers with $a_j < b_j \forall j \in J$.

If $((a_j,b_j))_{j\in J}$ is a partition of $A$, then each $(a_j,b_j)$ is open and closed in $A$.

Proof: Each $(a_j,b_j)$ is open in $A$ because both $A$ and $(a_j,b_j)$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, $A-(a_j,b_j)=((-\infty,a_j)\cap A)\cup((b_j,\infty)\cap A)$ is a union of open sets in $A$, then so is $A-(a_j,b_j)$.
Now that the lemma is proved, we notice that:

$\mathbb{R}$ is locally connected, which is equivalent to saying that if $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathscr{C}|_{A}(x)=\bigcup \{X \subseteq A : x \in X \text{ and } X \text{ is connected}\}$ is the connected component in $A$ of each $x\in A$, then $\mathscr{C}(A)=(\mathscr{C}|_{A}(x))_{x\in A}$ (wich is a collection of intervals) is the unique partition of $A$ formed by connected - simultaneously - open and closed sets in $A$.

$\mathbb{R}$ is separable (meaning that it contains a countable dense subset), which implies that if $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, then $A$ is separable. And $A$ being separable implies that $A$ has the Cantor Property, which is, if $\mathscr{C}$ is a collection of open sets in $A$, then $\mathscr{C}$ is countable (This follows from the fact that every discrete subset of a separable space is countable).


Now, after noticing this, we conclude that the result follows immediately from the lemma.
I'm asking myself if the same result is also true in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. I mean, is it true that any open subset $A$ of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a unique countable union of disjoint open intervals?
Consider the following lemma:

(Lemma 2) Given $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, let $int_{\mathbb{R}} X$ mean the interior of $X$ in the real line and $int_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}X$ the interior of $X$ in the extended real line. Then $int_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}X \cap \mathbb{R} = int_{\mathbb{R}}X$. In particular, $X$ is open on $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $X$ is open on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Proof: The result is imediate because the following:

For each $p \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathscr{V} _{p} =((p- \delta, p+\delta))_{\delta >0}$ is a local basis of $p$ in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Now that the lemma is proved, we notice that properties (1) and (2) also hold in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Therefore, the statemant immediately holds if $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Indeed if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, then we conclude that $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and that an interval $I\subseteq A$ open in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ can only be of the form $(a,b)$. And in the contex of temma 1:

$A-(a_j,b_j)=([-\infty,a_j)\cap A)\cup((b_j,\infty]\cap A)$ still is a union of open sets in $A$.

Therefore, the results is true if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$
I'm finding it difficult to prove the result in the case of $A$ containing $\infty$ or $-\infty$, although it appears to be true. I would be grateful if someone could prove such a case.

Can you prove it for $A\subseteq[0,1]$ instead? It's homeomorphic to $\bar{\mathbb R}$, so the result carries over.

The fact that I couldnt prove it is because of the structure of the open sets in $[-\infty, \infty]$, wich is the same as the structure of the open sets in $[0,1]$. So no

Of course $(7,+\infty]$ is an open set in $\overline{\mathbb R}$.
